How to know whether client_session_keep_alive is set to true or not in the client side using snowflake?
I wrote the code below.
    parameters := url.Values{}
    parameters.Add("timezone", "UTC")
    parameters.Add("protocol", "https")
    parameters.Add("role", config.RoleName)
    parameters.Add("warehouse", warehouse)
    parameters.Add("client_session_keep_alive", "true")
    parameters.Add("statement_timeout_in_seconds", "600")
    dsns = append(dsns, dsn+"?"+parameters.Encode())

As you can see, I set the client_session_keep_alive as true to keep the session alive.
I also want to know that the session in the client side is really having the true value for the parameter client_session_keep_alive.
I found out the session ID but have hard time figuring out this session id's client_session_keep_alive value is true or false.
Do you have any suggestion for me?
I am using go snowflake.
Thanks,

If you're connected to the session then you can issue a SHOW PARAMETERS IN SESSION command. If you want to get the parameters that are/were in use for another session, I'm not sure that's possible
